# MonoTouch: TabItem BadgeValue

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, badge

Using `MonoTouch 5.4` on new `XCode` and `iOS` 6.0

**Old** ViewController In TabBarController code:

```
this.TabBarItem.BadgeValue = "5";
```

No longer works.

**New code**, changing to this does work:

```
this.TabBarController.TabBar.Items[theIndexOfTab].BadgeValue = "5";
```

By not work I mean the badge does not appear, the value is just ignored in the old case.

Comment: ahah, the names **iOS6** and **Xcode 4.5** are disclosed / public, including most *high level* features (i.e. what you can see on Apple site without logging in). By not working you mean it's not showing the badge ? or it's throwing? e.g. `TabBarItem` being `null`.

Comment: The badge doesn't appear, seems to just swallow the setting of the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is normal. Maybe your code was changed / refactored before the update ?

`TabBarItem` is defined in `UIViewController` and represent the *tab bar item* of *this* view controller.

So `this.TabBarItem` is the tab bar item of this *this* view controller, e.g. I used a `UITabBarController` in my code (let's call it `parent`).

`this.TabBarController.TabBar.Items[x]` would represent the *tab bar item* of one of the **child** view controller of *this* `parent`.

So when I create `child1` and `child2` (both instances of `UIViewController`) and assign them to `parent.ViewControllers` we get three instances of `UITabBarItem` (one for parent, one for each child) - but only two of them (the children will ever be visible).

E.g. from logging the handle values

```
2012-09-14 20:13:24.092 test1[47917:1507] parent.TabBarItem.Handle = 291086496
2012-09-14 20:13:24.094 test1[47917:1507] parent.TabBar.Items [0].Handle = 218412640
2012-09-14 20:13:24.094 test1[47917:1507] parent.TabBar.Items [1].Handle = 160885040
2012-09-14 20:13:24.095 test1[47917:1507] child1.TabBarItem.Handle = 218412640 
2012-09-14 20:13:24.096 test1[47917:1507] child2.TabBarItem.Handle = 160885040
```

So I can either do:

```
child1.TabBarItem.BadgeValue = "5"; // or
parent.TabBar.Items[0].BadValue = "5";
```

to get the same behaviour. However changing the `parent.TabBarItem` won't be visible anywhere (at least not in my case where this is the `RootViewController` of my test application).